# Optional with and without braces in String concatenation

Tags: java, string, concatenation, brackets

The first line behaves as I expect, the second line doesn't compile with the error message:

> The method println(char[]) is ambiguous for the type PrintStream

I don't understand, I thought the brackets with the optional are only for readability.

```
System.out.println("" + (string == null ? null : null));
System.out.println("" + string == null ? null : null);
```

Comment: The second line will be evaluated as `(("" + string == null) ? null : null)` which will confuse the compiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latter is read by the compiler as follows:

```
System.out.println( ( ("" + string) == null ) ? null : null);
```

So it has grouped `"" + string` together.

So this means that, regardless of the outcome of the condition, `null`, or `null` are returned. Now `null` has no dedicated type: any type of object can be `null`. So Java does not know what method to call for that. You could have written:

```
System.out.println(null);
```

and it will result in the *same* error. Since there are [a lot of methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print-char:A-) that could be invoked with a `null`:

> ```
> public void print(char[] s)
> public void print(String s)
> public void print(Object obj)
> ```

For the first code fragment, that is *not* the case, since the compiler interprets it as:

```
System.out.println( "" (string == null ? null : null));
```

So here you *add* `null` to a `String`. As a result, the output is also a `String` and so the compiler perfectly knows what method to pick.

Answer (score 0):

`+` operator has a higher precedence than `==`, hence in absence of parentheses,  `("" + string)`is evaluated first and then the conditional check is done.
The `System.out.println` method is overloaded. In cases of overloading the closest type of parameter to which the argument can be assigned to is chosen by the compiler. But here , null can be assigned to all the overloaded println methods as described in @Willem's answer , hence confusing the compiler and causing the compilation error.